# systemd --user Failed to set up standard output: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, systemd, services

I've created this unit for systemd (v241) on the file `/etc/systemd/user/foo.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo
After=mysqld.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
StandardOutput=append:/home/pioz/foo/logs/backend.log
StandardError=append:/home/pioz/foo/logs/backend.log
WorkingDirectory=/home/pioz/foo
ExecStart=/home/pioz/foo/backend/current/foo

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start the service with `systemd --user start foo` (without `sudo`) I get the following error:

```
foo.service: Failed to set up standard output: Permission denied
```

If I comment on the options `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` on the unit file, **the service starts correctly**.

I run the service as user `pioz`, a normal Linux user. The file `/home/pioz/foo/logs/backend.log` are writable from the `pioz` user, in fact I can edit the file with nano.

How can I solve this permission denied error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to run the service as a regular user, move the .service file in their `$HOME/.config/systemd/user` directory (check permissions, of course). Then run the service like this:

```
systemctl --user start foo.service
```